# How can I make the D3 ChartPlotter fill the entire space allocated to the control?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I am using a D3 ChartPlotter in my WPF application.
Unlike the default behaviour, I'd need the ChartPlotter to:

- Hide the Z & X Axis
- Resize / Scale the graph to fully fill the horizontal space allocated to the control (I don't want the margin that it has by default

I tried searching on the net, but the documentation on the D3 is really scarce and scattered (does someone have a comprehensive resource for learning how to use it?)

Thanks

Comment: Well, for the hide axis thing this should get you part way there:
    `<d3:ChartPlotter MainHorizontalAxisVisibility="Collapsed">`

Comment: I tried using that just now, but the attribute wasn't recognized.
I currently have the 0.3.0.0 version, runtime v2.0.50727.
Is there a more updated version? 
On the official codeplex site that's the only one available.

Comment: hrmm how about this: `<d3:ChartPlotter Name="plotter" MainHorizontalAxis="{x:Null}" MainVerticalAxis="{x:Null}">`